# Many existing check queries to MySQL vs load table and compare in php

Tags: php, mysql

The task is to find difference between 2 lists of items.

*First list* is located in MySQL table in the `indexed` `integer` field. So we can easily get it with `SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE otherfield = mycondition`. Let's imagine query result is about **5000 rows.**

*Second list* is located in my PHP script, I just downloaded it from web. Let it be **2000 rows**.

Most of list items are duplicated and should not be inserted in database.

**Way 1:** select 5000 rows from MySQL, compare it with *second list* using `array_diff` PHP function and make mass query `INSERT (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)....;`. So we have less MySQL queries but they are enough heavy.

**Way 2:** make foreach loop for my second list and check if every key exists in MySQL and insert if not.

Question is what way is more correct and cheaper for server?
Im asking because comparing process starts like every 30 minutes.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in PHP? The cheapest option is to do it in MySQL

Comment: IDK 8D just midnight mad ideas. In fact I'm already using way 2 in my project. Thanks

Comment: Or you could pass the 2k items as part of an in (...) or not in (...)  condition in the where clause of an sql query. But you should really try all solutions out and see which one works you the best.

Comment: If you put a unique key on `(field1,field2,field3)` you can simply `INSERT IGNORE` everything from the second list. Job done.

Comment: @Nick that is very useful, thanks!

Comment: @966p no worries - I'm glad it was helpful.